# For on JList setSelectedIndex

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jlist, animated-gif

Im trying to through a JList by a for, the objective is to animate a Gif, in every item of the JList I have an Image, and when I push the Animate Button the for pass through every item on the JList and changes the Image on the Icon of the JLabel.

My problem is that I don't know how to use a for un a JList with the `setSelectedIndex()` and the `getSelectedIndex()`.

Thanks for the help.

**I was trying with:**

```
on = true;
while(on){
    for(int i=0; i <=list.getSelectedIndex();i++){
            list.setSelectedIndex(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to use something like a Swing Timer to increment your selection for you.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `JList` for animations. `JLabel`s are much better options. Check [this out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html), it explains how to use images.

To answer your question, the `for` should be changed to iterate to list size (`list.getModel().getSize()`), and not to selected index, which is (obviously) the index of the selected item. Also, you might want a delay between each for iteration.

Comment: I know, but its only for do an Example.

The problem is that I need a Thread for update the Jframe that im drawing every time the selectedIndex is change it.